# Can someone explain "diff = \ floor(a - b))" in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to understand the statement. It is diff  = \ floor(a - b)). What does the \ mean in this statement?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Appears to be a syntax error, as the statement is incomplete.

Comment: your example raises a syntax error. is it even working for you? If you mean something else, please your question with details

Comment: I don't see how we can call this a dup when all we really have is a syntax error. Does this code appear on two lines?

Answer (score 1):

`\` means the code continues on the next line

Comment: Assuming the backslash is immediately followed by a newline, anyway.

Comment: I think OP needs to clean up the example before we can know. The code has a backslash and an extra closing paren. Maybe its a fragment of a longer expression. Maybe its flat out wrong.